# Spring MVC. Autowired exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Использую в одном проекте и xml и annotations конфигурации. 
Когда пытаюсь сделать `@Autowired` в классе конфигурации spring-security, выбивает ошибку

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.khodan.caferacer.service.UserService com.khodan.caferacer.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.khodan.caferacer.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
```

И:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.khodan.caferacer.service.UserService com.khodan.caferacer.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.khodan.caferacer.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
... 25 more


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.khodan.caferacer.service.UserService com.khodan.caferacer.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.khodan.caferacer.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 55 more
```

Сам интерфейс UserService:

```
public interface UserService extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    public User findByEmail(String email);

}
```

Класс UserDetailServiceImpl, который и выкидывает данную ошибку:

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserService userService){ 
    this.userService = userService;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userService.findByEmail(name);

    if(user==null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User: "+name+" not found");
    }

    ModelUserDetails principal = ModelUserDetails.getBuilder()
                .firstName(user.getFirstName())
                .id(user.getId())
                .lastName(user.getLastName())
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .role(user.getRole())
                .socialSignInProvider(user.getSignInProvider())
                .username(user.getEmail())
                .build();

    return principal;
}
```

}

root-context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
 xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

 xsi:schemaLocation=
 "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

<!-- Включаем опцию использования конфигурационных аннотаций (@Annotation-based 
    configuration) -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Определяем папки, в которых будем автоматически искать бины-компоненты 
    (@Component, @Service) -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.khodan.caferacer" />

<!-- Sets the Entity Manager Factory, Data source and the JPA implementation 
    framework -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.khodan.caferacer.model" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/caferacer" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
</bean>

<!-- Provides auto-injecting EntityManager into the DAOs field with annotation 
    @PersistenceContext -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<!-- Provides translation native under layer Exceptions into Spring Exceptions 
    in DAOs classes with annotation @Repository -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<!-- Provides declarative transaction management -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="entityManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.project.traceplace">
    <!-- Avoids to duplicate class scan in root-context and application-servlet.xml -->
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

В этом файле так же выбивает ошибку автовайрета:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login/authenticate")
        .failureUrl("/login?error=bad_credentials")
    .and()
        .logout()
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                        "/auth/**",
                        "/login",
                        "/signup/**",
                        "/user/register/**"
                        ).permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
    .and()
        .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return (PasswordEncoder) new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
}

 @Bean
 public SocialUserDetailsService socialUserDetailsService() {
    return new SocialUserDetailsServiceImpl(userDetailsService());
 }

 @Bean
 public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsServiceImpl(userService);
 }
```

}

Comment: Вы особо не предоставили информации, чтобы можно было ответить на вопрос. Выкладывайте конфиги приложения. Чтобы подцепился репозиторий над `UserService` либо должна быть аннотация `@Repository`, либо в XML включен тэг `jpa:repositories`.

Comment: Да, и два раза на конструкторе и поле `@Autowired` ставить не нужно. Лучше уберите конструктор совсем, и делайте инжект через сеттер.

Comment: у меня добавлена аннотация `@Repository` но не помогло

Comment: @enzo то есть это `@Autowired
private UserService userService;` удалить полностью?

Comment: @enzo ясделал но тут таже история:
`Error creating bean with name 'securityContext': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.khodan.caferacer.service.UserService com.khodan.caferacer.config.SecurityContext.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.khodan.caferacer.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. `

Comment: @Autowired ставится там, где вы делаете инжект. Если через приватное поле, то над ним, если через конструктор - над конструктором, через сеттер - над сеттером. У вас она дублируется. В каком пакете находится `UserService`?

Comment: @enzo в пакете со всеми сервисами. 
обновил вопрос, добавился еще один конфиг файл с этим же вопросом

Comment: @enzo вместо userService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public setUserService(UserService userService) { 
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    // ...
}
```

**SecurityContext**

```
public class SecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {    
       auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: The constructor UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserDetailsService) is undefined.
Но в UserDetailsServiceImpl в конструктор мне надо передавать именно тот ЮзерСервис.

Comment: Конструктор в UserDetailsServiceImpl не нужен, уберите его. В ответе инжект делается через сеттер.

Comment: `В ответе инжект делается через сеттер.` не понимаю, что это значит ..

Comment: И еще. В примере по которому я делаю сейчас, указано, что в секюрити контекст, должен быть именно userService;
`Add an UserRepository field to the configuration and annotate the field with the @Autowired annotation.`

Comment: Можно и так сделать. Но вы намешали все в кучу. Если вы создаете объект UserDetailsServiceImpl  вручную и передаете в него UserService  через конструктор, то зачем пишете Autowired внутри UserDetailsServiceImpl, да еще дважды. Он там тогда вообще не нужен. Разберитесь как DI в спринге работает, что делает аннотация Bean, какие есть типы инжектов. Гарантированно поможет.